# SQLAlchemy Relationships: One field, multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html

I'm migrating my code from SQLite to SQLAlchemy for future migration to a different database engine.

I currently have the following SQL statement to build one of my tables:

```
c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cluster_relationships
        (
            plan_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            parent_cluster TEXT,
            child_cluster TEXT NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(plan_id) REFERENCES plan_listing(plan_auto_id),
            FOREIGN KEY(plan_id, parent_cluster) REFERENCES cluster_detail(plan_id, cluster_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY(plan_id, child_cluster) REFERENCES cluster_detail(plan_id, cluster_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            PRIMARY KEY(plan_id, parent_cluster, child_cluster)
        )
    ''')
```

From my reading I think what I want to accomplish has to be managed via a `relationship` but I'm new to the terminology and it isn't quite clicking yet.

**I Know this doesn't look like SQL Alchemy, I'm using a json-esq table schema and passing it through a constructor**

```
"cluster_relationships": {
    "plan_id":{"type":None, "nullable":False, "primary_key":True, "ForeignKey":ForeignKey("plan_listing.plan_auto_id")},
    "parent_cluster":{"type":String, "primary_key":True, "ForeignKey":ForeignKey("cluster_detail.cluster_no")},
    "child_cluster":{"type":String, "nullable":False, "primary_key":True, "ForeignKey":ForeignKey("cluster_detail.cluster_no")},
},
```

Originally I thought something like this might work (but it doesn't):

```
"plan_id":{"type":None, "nullable":False, "primary_key":True, "ForeignKey":ForeignKey(["plan_listing.plan_auto_id", "cluster_detail.plan_id"])}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to create the foreign key constraints?

Comment: Yes, with the field linked to both tables